# FlowDocument How to Include unformatted text (e.g. Code Example)

Tags: .net, text, include, flowdocument

I wish to include some code examples into a FlowdDocument so that the text keeps its original format. How do I achieve this? It would be nice if I could add elements to provide keyword highlighting whilst retaining the original indentation and spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Putting xml:space="preserve" on the paragraph element achieves what I want.